# enabling pagination inside wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, pagination, redirect

i have a specific single page which display a single post.
the thing is that i want to display below it all the other posts which have the same special meta data and i made that to work as well.

the problem starts when i try to make pagination to the list of the posts below.

the single post url is something like that:

```
blog.com/somepost
```

and the pagination link to the second page of posts below looks someting like this

```
blog.com/somepost/page/2
```

and wordpress automatically redirects me back to

```
blog.com/somepost
```

how can i prevent it from redirecting me back?

btw, i"m using something like that:

i"m doing something like this:

```
while( have_posts() ):  the_post();

   //here printing the single post          

endwhile;

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;


$args = array(
   'meta_key' => '_btree_project_id',
   'meta_value' => $post->ID,
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'paged' => $paged,
   'posts_per_page' => 8
);

$temp = $wp_query;

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

while( have_posts() ): the_post();

   //looping through the related posts here 

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reading I've done about WordPress pagination gives me the impression that it is an imperfect feature.  It requires the global var $wp_query which stems from the WP_Query object.  WP_Query holds the global $wp_query which is necessary for making even basic pagination work.  Custom queryies don't have access to $wp_query, nor do they own a var to control pagination.  I assume you are using a custom query to grab that single post, and as [this article](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/19/paging-and-custom-wordpress-loops/) points out, with custom queryies:

> the “fix” is to trick WordPress into
>   using the global $wp_query variable
>   when using our own custom loops.

The article gives an example of utiilizing the global var in your custom query so that you have access to the query_vars that make pagination possible.

I expect that your permalink structure and a custom query that I'm guessing you are using might not be working because the global $wp_query var isn't available during your loop to show related posts.

What does your code to get, display,  and paginate the related posts look like?  Can you post?

Comment: hi,

actually what you are describing is not the problem,
first i use the $wp_query to show the single post which belongs to that page.

next, i"m redefining the $wp_query var to hold a new WP_Query object
with the related posts parameters (and pagnation data, which works fine BTW).

the thing is when i try to go so
theblog.com/postname/page/2

it automatically redirects me back to
theblog.com/postname

before it event prints something..

Comment: Thanks for the code update, maybe the problem is with .htacces as posed here: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-with-custom-permalinks-broke-with-upgrade-to-30

Comment: And maybe use this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/category-pagination-fix/